# Touch points displaced

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

I'm facing a problem with my android device. My touchpad points are displaced. E.g. if I touch the first row then it's touched second row, if I touch "w" then it touches "s". Now what I need to do?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You should consider replacing the digitizer

Comment: This is a function of screen calibration, which can degrade over time. There are a few apps that come up in a Play Store search which sound like they can assist you to re-calibrate. Search: "calibrate screen".

Comment: Time to replace the screen guard